# How to enable animated effects when texting from iphone 8 running 16.4?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

When I was using IOS 15.6 on my iphone 8, whenever I sent "happy birthday" or "congrats" or "happy new year" to another iphone user, it showed balloons or fireworks on my phone too.  However, now after updating my phone to IOS 16.4, sometimes it appears, sometimes it doesn't.

I asked a couple people I sent messages to and they said they didn't see the effects so my guess is if it appears on my phone, it appears on theirs too.  If it doesn't on mine, it doesn't on theirs either.

What do I need to do to make it appear all the time?  Is there a setting on the receiving phone that needs to be set for animated effects to appear on my phone?  Do they need to be on the same IOS version as me for the animated effects to work too?

Comment: Try to turn off Reduce Motion. Go to **Settings > General > Accessibility > Reduce Motion** and disable it.

Comment: Come back to me with the results! :)

Comment: Press and hold the “blue send arrow” on the rightmost portion of the message box.  You will be given a menu of effects to choose from.  This will ensure the message is sent with the effect.